# jquery table find closest tr containing and get td text

Tags: jquery, row, html-table

This datatables has row-reordering so its drag and drop. What I am trying to do is find the Parent this row is dropped into and get the Parent id. Hopefully someone can tell me where I am going wrong...

This line successfully gives me the tr id

```
var line = parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
```

So I'm using this to get the closest above Parent (check the image)

```
var s = $(this).find('tr:contains("Parent")');
```

What I can't seem to do is get to any td value

```
var s = $(this).find('tr:contains("Parent")').find('td:eq(17)').text()
```

I've also tried this

```
var s = $(this).closest('tr').prevAll('tr.Parent:first > td:nth-child(17)').text()
```

Link to an image of the table http://postimg.org/image/rlamm9osd/

jsfiddle with table code http://jsfiddle.net/Lmcfccmo/

Comment: what is `this` here?

Comment: The HTML would be a lot more useful than a picture :)

Comment: the context of this is  <tr id="1897" class="odd ui-sortable-handle" role="row" style="">     using console.log(this);

Comment: Without your full HTML, this question can only be answered with guesswork (as it is dependant on the actual content/classes). Your examples are contradictory (`Parent` used as both text and as a class). Please supply the HTML of the actual page (before your question is closed). Thanks :)

Comment: I've tried extracting the html from the browser but it seems datatables is not rendering the entire table html as I've only got the skeleton I use as the base before using javascript/datatables constructs to generate each column and row (all the data is loaded via json)  - so I'm guessing partly its answering why I'm not able to select a cell using jquery...

Comment: Use the F21 DOM inspector in Chrome. You can cut & paste the appropriate part of the DOM tree from there.

Comment: I have narrowed it down somewhat - apologies for not getting all the code here, its just a sizable amount . This script gets all the rows with Parent            var s = $(this).parent().find("tr:contains('Parent'):first > td:nth-child(17)").text();   how do I change it just to get the closest above?

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle with table code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmcfccmo/

Comment: Thank you... Having the HTML makes it much easier as there is a far simpler way than you were trying. Each row contains the parent `ID=""` value, so simply use that value in a jQuery ID selector (as IDs must be unique on the page to be valid HTML). Working example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to simply take the "parent ID" value from column (index 14) and use it to find the row that simply has `ID="that parent number"`:

e.g.

```
  var parent = $('#' + $(this).children().eq(14).text());
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Lmcfccmo/5/

Comment: Awesome & Thank you - learned a few new things - thanks also for the F21 DOM inspector in Chrome hint...